# Where to download a 6 man Nalimov endgame tablebase?

Tags: endgame, tablebases

Can anyone tell me whereabouts I can download a 6 man Nalimov endgame tablebase? I've seen some websites with 6 man Nalimov (case in point: http://contentdb.emule-project.net/view.php?pid=1630). However, so far all I have come across is dead links.

Can someone able to point me to some working link(s)?

Answer (score 4):

From the ICCF site:
Players who wish to have access to the 7 men tablebases may purchase any of the following programs: ChessOK Aquarium 2017, Houdini Aquarium 2017, Houdini PRO Aquarium 2017, Chess Assistant 17 with Houdini 5  and Chess Assistant 17 PRO with Houdini 5 PRO.

Free Android application
One more way to access 7-man tablebases without having a key is to use Android application.

Search for Lomonosov Tablebases or use https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.convekta.android.lomonosovtb

Alternatively, if players only want access to 6 men tablebases they may visit this page to use the 6-piece Nalimov tablebases: http://chessok.com/?page_id=361

Comment: i'm not interested in online access to an egtb, i'm interested in actually downloading the 6-man Nalimov egtb files (much like you can readily do with the 6-man syzygy egtb).

Comment: I think you can buy the DVD, but I haven't found a downloadable purchase.

Answer (score 0):

http://kirill-kryukov.com/chess/tablebases-online/

Just to show where I got the links from.  Site came from Arena's Chess GUI's homepage.  Site states they had permission from  Eugene Nalimov & Andrew Kadatch.

http://www.playwitharena.com/?User_Files%2C_Engines:Axon%2C_EloStat%2C_Nalimov:Nalimov_Tablebases

Found the link initially.  Very informative for computer chess in general.
https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Nalimov+Tablebases